# Move contents of all sub subdirectories up into just their subdirectories

Tags: files, move

The problem I am facing is that I have a directory that contains thousands of subdirectories, each of those subdirectories contain more subdirectories, and inside of all of those are images.

What I have are thousands of these:

/1056/7624/image.png

I basically want to eliminate the 7624 directory here so that I end up with thousands of these instead:

/1056/image.png

I tried `mv */*/* */*` but that just freaked out... is this even possible to do with a terminal command?

I'm trying to do this so I can use this multifile uploader without going into 50 directories just to grab 50 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for dir in */*; do
  if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
    ( 
      cd "$dir"
      mv -n * ..
      cd ..
      rmdir "$( basename "$dir" )"
    )
  fi
done
```

Be aware that any duplicated file or subdirectory names will *not* be moved and so the deep directories in those cases will *not* be removed, due to still containing files.

Comment: So run this from the directory that contains the initial subdirectories?

Comment: Given your example of `/1056/7624/image.png`, run this from the directory that _contains_ the `1056` directory.

Comment: Oddly I get a bunch of `rmdir: failed to remove '1103/1560': No such file or directory` for every one of them

Comment: It is moving the images up one directory though, just not removing the subdirectories, even though I can verify the ones in the error do exist.

Comment: Fixed, I forgot to trim the outer directory from the `rmdir`.

Answer (score -1):

this will move all files from current dir and any sub-dirs, up to the current level. Renaming any files with the same name with a number appended.

```
find ./ -type f -print -exec mv --backup=numbered {} . \;
```

then you can make sure you got everything with a

```
find ./ -mindepth 2 -type f
```

Comment: downvotes for literally no reason. i like it.